# Using Worksheet Functions In A Macro

Tags: vba, excel

I have an array of integers in VBA from which I would like to get the upper and lower quartiles.

I would like to use this method to get them: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836118.aspx

The documentation suggests you can use an array to do this, but when I try to run my code (below) I get an error saying **Unable to get the Quartile property of the WorksheetFunction class**

Please assist.

```
Dim totalsalesthatday() As String
Dim doINeedTo As Boolean
Dim totalsalesthatdayAverage As Integer
Dim randomnumberthingy As Integer
Dim quartile1 As Integer
Dim quartile3 As Integer
Dim iqr As Integer
Dim upper As Integer
Dim lower As Integer
quantity = 0
For Each queryaddress In worksheetname.Range("A2:A21")
query = queryaddress.Value
offsetnum = 0
If offsetnum = 0 Then
doINeedTo = True
End If
For Each daysoftheweek In Sheets
quantity = 0
If InStr(1, daysoftheweek.Name, worksheetnamename, vbTextCompare) > 0 And daysoftheweek.ListObjects.Count > 0 Then
Set itemaddress = daysoftheweek.Columns(5).Find(query, , xlValues, xlWhole)
If Not itemaddress Is Nothing Then
        firstAddress = itemaddress.Address
        Do
Set itemrow = itemaddress.EntireRow
quantity = quantity + itemrow.Columns(6).Value
Set itemaddress = daysoftheweek.Columns(5).FindNext(itemaddress)
Loop While Not itemaddress Is Nothing And itemaddress.Address <> firstAddress
End If
   offsetnum = offsetnum + 1
   ReDim Preserve totalsalesthatday(offsetnum)
   totalsalesthatday(offsetnum) = daysoftheweek.ListObjects.Item(1).ListRows.Count
   queryaddress.Offset(0, offsetnum).Value = quantity
   worksheetname.Range("A1").Offset(0, offsetnum).Value = daysoftheweek.Name
End If
Next
If doINeedTo Then
quartile1 = WorksheetFunction.Quartile(totalsalesthatday, 1)
quartile3 = WorksheetFunction.Quartile_Inc(totalsalesthatday, 3)
iqr = quartile3 - quartile1
upper = quartile3 + (iqr * 1.5)
lower = quartile1 - (iqr * 1.5)
```

The error in question is at this line: `quartile1 = WorksheetFunction.Quartile(totalsalesthatday, 1)`

Comment: Seems like you answered your own question. If you look at the data types that the `.Quartile` function is supposed to take and then look at the data types you are giving it, they don't match up. Try changing your data types.

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize that an array in VBA could **not** be a string, I thought that is how you declared an array. Changing it to `Dim totalsalesthatday() As Integer` worked, thanks! :)

Comment: Ill put it in the answer section then. You're Welcome!

Comment: @SummerDeveloper I know this is five years old but you should know that array in VBA can be strings or integers or variants or doubles or singles... they can be of almost any type. VBA was not your problem. Your problem was the Quartile() function expects an array of numbers, but you were passing it an array of strings. That's it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.Quartile` function parameters are an array and a double. Try changing your data types.